# ActionBar Sherlock not showing up. What might be the error?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I included ActionBarSherlock as a library. Added this in manifest.xml:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
```

This is what I wrote in my activity:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragment();
            newFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment, "dialog");
                ft.commit();

            getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Still, the action bar doesn't show up. Any small sample code would help or remarks as to where I am going wrong should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the video I filmed, which is now part of the FAQ's of this project to ensure you followed all the setup instructions. This is a really common problem.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k

Comment: Have you defined your activity as extending "FragmentActvity" rather than the normal "Activity"?

Comment: Yes, I've. The problem I am facing here is even though it is showing up at the splash screen, it is not visible everywhere. How do I use it globally?

Comment: You do not need to set it for every activity, just the application.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository at https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

In the samples folder you will find plenty of options on how to implement.

You can even import the projects into your IDE and copy paste if needed